# getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when comparing char array to KeyEvent

Tags: arrays, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder, keyevent

I am building a JavaFX typing application and am trying to check if the user input matches the letters they need to type. I am doing this through a KeyEvent and comparing that individually to the matching index in the array. Upon doing this I get many errors, the main cause being

`Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 117 out of bounds for length 5 at sample.Controller.detectInputAreaKeyEvent(Controller.java:51)`

controller

```
    @FXML
    private void detectInputAreaKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        char[] splitter = textToType.toCharArray();
        for (char c : splitter) {
            if (event.getText().equals(splitter[c])) {
                System.out.println("right letter");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("wrong letter");
            }
        }

    }
```

FXML

```
      <StackPane fx:id="typingArea" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Text fx:id="sixsixsix" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="urmom">
               <font>
                  <Font size="40.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <TextArea fx:id="inputArea" onKeyPressed="#detectInputAreaKeyEvent" opacity="0.29" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
         </children>
      </StackPane>
```

main class

```
String textToType = "test";
```

Comment: Your loop `for (char c : splitter)` is a for-each loop, not a traditional for loop, which means the `c` is each element in the array and not an index.

Comment: i changed it to a regular for loop and it still gives the same error `for (int i = splitter.length; i > 0; i--) {`

Comment: Because arrays are 0-based (i.e. the first index is `0` and the last index is `length - 1`). Not to be disparaging, but perhaps you should review the basics of Java (e.g. arrays, the different for loops, etc.) to make sure you have a good understanding of the fundamentals.